# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY - why so?

Tags: java, android

I am running into a problem when I do an API call to retrieve the data I wish to acquire and I have tried alot of fixes but I can't get it to work.

I get the error `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`

Out of my understanding it retrieved an object instead of an array. I have tried changing JsonArray to JsonObject but it will still give me the same error.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

All help is appreciated!

```
public static JsonArray readData = new JsonArray();

Call<Post> call = jsonApiServiceFive.getAfashrmData("", GlobalConstants.deviceSerialNumber, "", "", "", "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: readData loaded.");
                readData = response.body().getData();
            }
```

```
public class Post {

@SerializedName("ArrayOfTextValue")
private JsonArray ArrayOfTextValue

public JsonArray getData(){
   return ArrayOfTextValue;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you expecting JSON when the data is XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh... after a good sleep i immediately noticed the problem.
`Call<Post>` had to be `Call<JsonArray>`
Post is an object i create in my code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your dataset is what you are using or not because that's XML but you tend to get that error when attempting to serialise json object when it's an array.

```
"json_object" : { "item": "value" }
```

vs

```
"json_array": [{"item":"value1"}, {"item":"value2"}]
```

I can't verify if it's JsonArray causing the issue.
The way i usually do serialisation and deseralisation of json lists is to use an arraylist of my objects

```
@SerializedName("entries")
@Expose
private ArrayList<DiaryEntry> diaryEntries;
```